# How to get RDS tags?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get a tag for rds instances.
I use node js and it works as async so I can not get the results properly.
Please Reply with quote

added:
An rds instance can have multiple tags.
I wanted to import only certain tags from the rds instance's tags.
However, the instance and tag did not match because it works async.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require("request");
AWS.config.update({region:'ap-northeast-1'});
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'test'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
var rds = new AWS.RDS();

rds.describeDBInstances(function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.DBInstances.length; i++) {
        var instance = data.DBInstances[i];
        var clusterName = instance.DBClusterIdentifier;
        var instanceName = instance.DBInstanceIdentifier;
        var resourceName = 'arn:aws:rds:ap-northeast-1:231497262134:db:' + instanceName;
        var params = {
            ResourceName: resourceName,
        };

        rds.listTagsForResource(params, function(err, data) {
            var serviceTag = ''
            data.TagList.forEach((tag) => {
                if (tag.Key.toLowerCase() === 'service' && tag.Value.length > 0) {
                    serviceTag = tag.Value;
                }        
            })
            console.log(instanceName, serviceTag)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Does the code run? What is the `data` response? Is there an error? Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: Do not ignore the error, Check for the err before accessing data!

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it with async and await syntax.
Thanks for the comments.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require("request");
AWS.config.update({region:'ap-northeast-1'});
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'test'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
var rds = new AWS.RDS();


rds.describeDBInstances(async (err, data) => {
    for(var i=0; i<data.DBInstances.length; i++) {
        var instance = data.DBInstances[i];
        var clusterName = instance.DBClusterIdentifier;
        var instanceName = instance.DBInstanceIdentifier;
        var resourceName = 'arn:aws:rds:ap-northeast-1:231497262134:db:' + instanceName;


        let params = {
            ResourceName: resourceName,
        };

        let tags = await rds.listTagsForResource(params).promise();
        var serviceTag = ''
        tags.TagList.forEach((tag) => {
            if (tag.Key.toLowerCase() === 'service' && tag.Value.length > 0) {
                serviceTag = tag.Value;
            }        
        })


        console.log(clusterName + ',' + instanceName + ',' + serviceTag)
    }
})
```